# Disable Module by Product/Site

Tags: magento-1.9, module, extensions

I have a module in my shop that is only there for development purposes and can only be accessed in a special product via a cookie. All other products load module, but do not use it, as it is a special configurator.

Is it possible to enable/disable loading that module by a specified parameter, such as a specified site or a specified product?

Answer (score 0):

Not in a practical way no, the code to determine if the module should be enabled or disabled would (should) be in the module. So if the module is not enabled it would not be able to detect and disable/enable based on the request.

You could do something before initialising Magento to determine if the module should be enabled and edit the file to re-enable it if the request meets the criteria. This however would need caching to be turned off, or refreshed on each request (to reload the configuration). This would in turn not be beneficial.

An alternative depending on what your module does would be to wrap it in a system configuration option for enabling it. Im assuming the problem is your seeing it work when others request access, so if you wrap all processing code in a simple check then return if the module is not enabled that might help you.

```
Mage::app()->getCurrentStore()->isOutputEnabled('myModule');
```

Another approach you could potentially use (again without knowing what the module is doing) would be to restructure your approach such that it isnt actually a Magento module, instead a library file that could be pulled in only when required.